# Nested array maps inside of reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

have a complex redux situation I am working with and cant quite get what I need. I have 2 objects, `Track` and `Target`

```js
interface Track {
  id: number,
  ...other fields
}

interface Target {
  id: number (same as the Track)
  tracks: Track[]
  ...other fields
}
```

what I am trying to do is when I fetch the tracks I am trying to see if there are any targets that have the same ID (one target to many tracks), and if it does then add the track to that target's tracks array, otherwise - create a new target with that Track id and put the track in the tracks array

```js
case TargetActionTypes.FETCH_TARGETS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    targets: [
      action.tracks.map((track: Track) =>
        state.targets.map((target: Target) =>
          track.target_id === target.id
            ? {
                ...target,
                tracks: [...target.tracks, track]
              }
            : {
                id: track.target_id,
                visible: true,
                tracks: [track]
              }
        )
      )
    ]
  }
```

I think this is on the right track but typescript is complaining because I think maybe its nesting things one level too deep because of the nested loops? Typescript errors here

```
Types of property 'targets' are incompatible. Type '{ tracks: Track[]; id: number; visible: boolean; }[][][]' is not assignable to type 'Target[]'.
Type '{ tracks: Track[]; id: number; visible: boolean; }[][]' is missing the following properties from type 'Target': id, visible, tracks",
```

Comment: So the parent is set to type Target[], but the map is returning a nested array, That is why TS is complaining, can you please try this in plain vanilla JS with the hard coded response, so that we know what o/p atleast we get, and we can figure it out

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments, property `targets` in your state has type `Target[]`, but what you are assigning to it is not. `state.targets.map(...)` returns an array of targets, so `Target[]`, then it is returned from callback function to another `map` so `action.tracks.map(...)` returns an array of arrays of `Target` (so `Target[][]`) and then you are wrapping it in a pair of square brackets, so it becomes `Target[][][]`. Call to `.map` returns an array, so if you wrap it in square braces, you get array in array, so the first step is to remove those.

Now to get rid of another level of nesting you will need to get rid of `.map`, which won't quite work in this case, because `.map` just transforms one array to another array with the same length. Here the length can vary, so `.map` is not a very good fit. The simplest way is just not using built-in methods and going with a loop:

```
const targets: Target[] = []
for(const track of tracks) {
  const target = targets.find(target => target.id === track.target_id)

  if (target) target.push(track)
  else targets.push({id: track.target_id, visible: true, tracks: [track]})
}
```

Maybe you could make this algorithm a little faster by not going over the entire array of `targets` in every iteration

```
const targets: Target[] = []
const cache: Record<number, Target> = {}

for(const track of tracks) {
  if(track.target_id in cache) {
    cache[track.target_id].tracks.push(track)
  } else {
    targets.push(cache[track.target_id] = {
      id: track.target_id, 
      visible: true, 
      tracks: [track]
    })
  }
}
```

If you really want some built-in methods then `.reduce` would fit better:

```
tracks.reduce<Target[]>(
  (targets, track) => {
    const target = targets.find(target => target.id === track.track_id)

    if(!target) {
      targets.push({id: track.target_id, visible: true, tracks: [track]})
    } else {
      target.tracks.push(track)
    }
    return targets
    
  }
)
```

Or if you don't like mutating objects

```
tracks.reduce<Target[]>(
  (targets, track) => {
    const index = targets.findIndex(target => target.id === track.target_id)

    if(index < 0) {
      return [...targets, {id: track.target_id, visible: true, tracks: [track]}]
    } 
    return [
      ...targets.slice(0, index),
      {...targets[index], tracks: [...targets[index].tracks, track]},
      ...targets.slice(index),
    ]
  }
)
```

But I don't see much advantage in this code, because it is not very readable and unnecessarily copies elements between arrays so many times